# Strange behavior in third argument / regex match in BASH 4.3.46

Tags: regex, bash, arguments

Preface: I am just learning bash scripting. So there is a good chance I have done something ignorant with the following code.

Code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    ip=$1
    first=$2
    last =$3

if [[ $first =~ ^(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$ ]] && [[ $last =~ ^(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$ ]]; then

    echo "Valid Range"

else
    echo "Invalid Range!"
    fi




if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0]$ ]]; then
    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS='.'
    ip=($ip)
    IFS=$OIFS
    [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
        && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]


    echo "Valid IP"
else
    echo "Invalid IP"
    fi
```

As you can see the regex applying to Argument 2 is the same as the regex applying to argument 3. But providing the same input for the 2 arguments results in different outcomes ex.

```
./test.sh 192.168.1.0 25 25

Invalid Range!
Valid IP
```

I have altered the code to figure out which regex fails and it is the regex for $3 every time. I have even changed the position of the arguments in the script. Ex changing the IP to $3 and reordering arguments will cause the regex for IPs to fail even when using a known good IP.

So the Questions would be:

Am I doing something wrong?

Is something wrong with bash?

Any help from the bash gurus would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you would like me to add the altered code I used to test. I didn't want to clog the question with too much code if not needed. But I can add it if requested.

Comment: You have a typo in the assignment to `last`: it should be `last=$3` (no spaces around the `=`).

Comment: Did you already try to insert `set -x` into your script (e.g. as 2nd line)? This enables trace mode and helps to debug bash scripts.

Comment: Also, do not use regular expressions to verify numerical ranges; just use `if (( $value >= 1 && $value <= 255)); then`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you chepner. I was up until 7 this trying to figure this out. I guess thats what happens. So correcting the typo fixed it, however I really appreciate th better way to validate numerical ranges. I have updated and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Scheff, I have not used the set -x option. I will definitely look into this today as I am sure it will be useful in the near future.